# Simple Qt threading mechanism with progress?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I want to look for files with given extensions recursively from a given root directory and to display the number of files currently found in my GUI.
Since this kind of processing may be long, the GUI may be blocked.
I could just wait for the end of the processing and get the file count, but I am learning Qt (PyQt), so I see this as a training.

So I have read Qt doc:
[When to Use Alternatives to Threads](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/thread-basics.html#when-to-use-alternatives-to-threads), and I don't think it's for me.

Then I read:
[Choosing an Appropriate Approach](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/threads-technologies.html#choosing-an-appropriate-approach), and I think my solution is the first one:

> Run a new linear function within another thread, optionally with
>   progress updates during the run

But in this case you have 3 choices:

> Qt provides different solutions:
>
> - Place the function in a reimplementation of QThread::run() and start the QThread. Emit signals to update progress. OR
> - Place the function in a reimplementation of QRunnable::run() and add the QRunnable to a    QThreadPool. Write to a thread-safe variable
>     to update progress. OR
> - Run the function using QtConcurrent::run(). Write to a thread-safe variable to update progress.

Could you tell me how to choose the best one?
I have read some "solutions" but I'd like to understand why you should use one methodology instead of another one.

And also since I am looking for files, I may have a directory in which many files would match the search criteria. So it would mean lots of interruptions. Is there something special to keep in mind regarding this?

Thank you!

Comment: I've only got experience w/ QThread, and not a whole lot at that.  But, from what I know (and based on the chart) the other options cannot received SIGNALS. So, I'm not sure how you'd handle a user-initiated cancel, for example.

Comment: It's an interesting point of view. I haven't noticed the part regarding signals. That's helping a lot! I the meantime I had a look at the `QThread`, and I found that Qt doc is not perfect regarding this: https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: I should read this as I need to add QThreads to an existing project.  Well, they're there, but not utilized fully.  One golden rule you need to remember is that any manipulation of a widget has to happen in the main thread, which is where signals and slots come into play, so take that into account.  Also note that there's a difference in QThread implementation between two versions of Qt4.  I *think* it's 4.7 and 4.8, so make sure to investigate that as well.

Comment: In fact, the change I was talking about specifically makes subclassing QThread obsolete... or at least not required.  So, confirm which version you have and then decide if that article is valid.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.3, so I can follow the guideline ie. not to subclass `QThread`. Thanks for the golden rule regarding widget handling. I'll keep that in mind. Btw, if you want to post a solution saying the stuff regarding communication thru signals, I'll gladly accept. That's the kind of answers I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Will do!.. right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know (hopefully more can chime in).
QThread offers support with signal interaction.  For example, you'd be able to stop your concurrent function with a signal.  Not sure how you'd do that with the other options, if at all.

Things to keep in mind: widgets all have to live in the main thread, but can communicate with other other threads via signals & slots.

Another quick thread on the topic w/ some decent bullet-points.
https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/50165/

Best of luck on your project, and welcome to Qt!